# Swift: for-in with two values

Tags: objective-c, swift

I started learning C some weeks ago and today I started learning Swift. The code is the following:

```
    import Foundation

let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 8, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0;
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
        }
    }
}
println(largest);
```

Why do I need *kind* in the for-in thingy? For "Prime", "Square", ..., right? Can I work with that somehow, too?

*“Add another variable to keep track of which kind of number was the largest, as well as what that largest number was.”*

How do I build that in?

Comment: If you are not interested in kind, use _ instead. for (_, numbers) in interestingNumbers...

Comment: Thanks for that input! I've edited my question. How do I work with kind and numbers at the same time? For example: I want to save which kind the numbers is. How do I do that?

Comment: At the time you remember the newest largest number "kind" contains whether that number came from Prime,Fibonacci or Square ;-)

Now try to remember that together with the value of that largest number you already store into "largest"

Comment: `import Foundation
var largest = 0;
var largestKind: String?;

let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 8, 16, 25],
]


for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
            largestKind = kind;
        }
    }

}
println("The number \(largest) is from the type \(largestKind)");
 `

That's my solution at the moment. Anyway, the output is "The number 25 is from the type Optional("Square")". I don't want that "Optional..."

Comment: Can't somebody help me?

Comment: Remove the interrogation mark if you don't want it optional: `var largestKind = ""`

Comment: Thanks for that! That's the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same question, this is another solution I've found. `var largestKind` is still optional because of `String?` but the exclamation mark at the end `\(largestKind!)` makes it possible to access the value without having that optional stuff around the actual content.

```
import Foundation
var largest = 0;
var largestKind: String?;

let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 8, 16, 25],
]


for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
            largestKind = kind;
        }
    }

}
println("The number \(largest) is from the type \(largestKind!).");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
var largest = 0;
var largestKind: String?;

let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 8, 16, 25],
]


for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
            largestKind = kind;
        }
    }

}
println("The number \(largest) is from the type \(largestKind)");
```

That's my solution at the moment. However, the output is

> The number 25 is from the type Optional("Square")

How do I get rid of the 'Optional("")? I just want the word Square. I tried removing the question mark (var largestKind: String?; to var largestKind: String;) but I get an error doing that.

Comment: `var largestKind = ""`